# Can I access another thread's resources in Java from a different thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, rabbitmq, connection

I have a situation where I want to access threads in Waiting or Blocked state and destroy their connections to an external Server. Is this possible without making a global variable that stores those connections? Can I access those connection objects from another Thread in Java?

To be more specific:

I had connections with a RabbitMQ Server which throttles connections when it reaches a particular memory threshold which in my case it has reached. So, the client hangs waiting for RabbitMQ server to unblock it which would never happen in my use case. So, I want to close those particular connections. I have tried sending interrupts to those threads but it seems like those threads are not recognizing interrupts and remain hanged indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

Resources do not belong to threads, Java doesn't care which thread has a reference to a `Socket` object for example.

You'll need a central `ConcurrentHashMap<Thread, Socket>` or something like that to make your connection objects visible to the outside. Or you can interrupt threads and let them kill the connection, since almost all things wait / blocking do throw `InterruptedException`s when you do so.

So in case you know which `thread` it is, it's typically something like

```
Socket socket = connectionMap.get(thread);
socket.close();
```

or

```
thread.interrupt();
```

which would go together with thread code like

```
Thread myThread = Thread.currentThread();
connect();
while(!myThread.isInterrupted()) {
    try {
        doStuff();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        myThread.interrupt(); // exception does not set interrupted state
    }
}
disconnect();
```

Comment: Thank You !! Though I find this answer absolute correct but my program is not recognizing Interrupts. I had a connection with a RabbitMQ Server which throttles connections when it reaches a particular memory threshold which in my case it has reached. So, the client hangs waiting for RabbitMQ server to unblock it which would never happen in my use case. So, I want to close those particular connections. But as I said, the Thread is showing true in Thread.isInterrupted() but it is still not getting InterruptedException by putting it in try catch.

Comment: @ArpanGupta You missed a great opportunity to make your question more specific and answerable by not including this information (that you specifically want to close RabbitMQ connections)

Comment: I will add that in the description, Thanks !

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt, Even though my real reason for asking this question is closing RabbitMQ connections, but apart from that, the thread should be able to get interrupted through myThread.interrupt()